# Method inside an array in C#

Tags: c#, json

I just got in contact with **C#** and I was wondering if it's possible to call a method inside an array. I have to say that I'm working with NoSQL database (**mongodb**).

This is mi code, and I want to call `data()` method inside that JSON.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");

    var document = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "date", 10/04/2018 },
        { "data", data() }
    };

    collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
    Console.Read();

}

static void data()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        var data = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "magnitude"+i, new BsonDocument{
                { "value", 5 }
                } }
            };
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Basically, what I'm trying to create with C# is this json below. I already did it with PHP and now, I'm trying to do it with C#.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abb735eb57dce214009035a"),
    "date" : 1262300400,
    "data" : {
        "magnitude1" : {
            "value" : 60
        },
        "magnitude2" : {
            "value" : 38
        },
        "magnitude3" : {
            "value" : 200
        },
        "magnitude4" : {
            "value" : 62
        },
        "magnitude5" : {
            "value" : 153
        },
        "magnitude6" : {
            "value" : 176
        },
        "magnitude7" : {
            "value" : 185
        },
        "magnitude8" : {
            "value" : 168
        },
        .
        .
        .
```

[image]

Comment: your code even in theoretical currently would fail as "data()" returns nothing.

Comment: @A. also its better to store value in a variable and then assign that variable to json object.

Comment: I don't see `mongodb` or `nosql` being relevant to the question at all since I assume the `data()` method is expected to be exectuted before `collection.InsertOneAsync(document)`. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've could solve it thanks to @Michael .Code below in case helps to anyone.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Collection");

    var document = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "date", 10/04/2018 },
        { "data", new BsonDocument{ getDocuments() } }
    };
    collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
    Console.Read();
}

static BsonDocument getDocuments()
{
    var documents = new BsonDocument();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var document = new BsonDocument
               {
                   { "magnitude" + i, new BsonDocument { { "value", 5 } } }
               };
         documents.AddRange(document);
     }
     return documents;
}
```

Comment: Copy that. Looks like BsonDocument is a list of itself; this I didn't realize.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods to gather data but I'm not sure exactly how you're asking it. Related to the code example I'll just give a simple run down, which is basic programming in general, not just C#.

You can write methods that return void or that return a variable of some type (at a minimum).

```
//Returns void
public void DoSomething() 
{
    //Do some work
    return; 
}

//Returns int
public int GetSomething() 
{ 
     int result = 100;
     return result;
}
```

When you have methods that return data you can use them as you would a variable; just remember the method will execute every time it's called so it's often best to save the data to a variable.  But for your example you can do something like this.

```
//other code ommitted
var document = new BsonDocument
{
    { "date", 10/04/2018 },
    { "data", getDocuments() }
};
//remaining code omitted


static List<BsonDocument> getDocuments()
{
    var documents = new List<BsonDocument>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        var document = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "magnitude" + i, new BsonDocument { { "value", 5 } } }
        };
        documents.Add(document);
    }
    return documents;
}
```

Now I modified the `data()` method to return a list of documents and changed the naming to match it but I'm not sure what you wanted to do with the method. That was my best assumption of what you were trying to accomplish by looking at your code so feel free to ignore all of it if it's wrong.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, however for some reason I got same error in `{ "data", getDocuments() }` it says `it cannot be converted from System.Collections.Generic.List<MongDB.Bson.BsonDocument> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String>`

Comment: I added more specific content for a better understanding

Comment: alright. it's already solve it! Thanks for your code, it helped me.